# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'device_info_plus' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am getting a build error while trying to run my flutter app on iOS.

The App is running perfectly on an android device.

I am using few third party packages as well,
I also tried removing the package, which seems to be causing the error,

After removing the package, The error is same, only module name is getting changed to some other package name like :

```
Parse Issue (Xcode): Module [Some other package name] not found
```

Any help is appreciated.